# Style Window Header line

Tags: wpf

I want to create a style for a window like in the image. So the triangle in the upper side of the window will be in the position of the mouse. How can i do it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't edit the window title bar in wpf. For this you need to set WindowStyle=None and add the usercontrol on top section and make it functional as a window header.

Comment: there is a link [Create-Custom-Windows-in-WPF-with-Ease](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140267/Create-Custom-Windows-in-WPF-with-Ease) which is very good. you can also implement your functionality like this.

Comment: ok. that's what i need. but still how do i make this triangle in the top of the window in the position of the mouse?

Comment: create a user control which has a triangle that moves with your mouse position and place it on top of your main window.